# Need sample javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, json, object, literals

I need a sample js object literal which can be accessed in the following way:

```
hist.undo[0].operation[0].x // would print '2' or whatever
hist.undo[0].operation[0].y // would print '21' or whatever
// [...]
hist.undo[2].operation[0].x // would print '32' or whatever
hist.undo[2].operation[0].y // would print '12' or whatever
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Toader Mihai Claudiu - No. I am new to JSON and am having trouble creating objects.

Comment: This post might help you better understand JavaScript objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704618/what-is-the-difference-between-var-thing-and-function-thing-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
test
<script>
hist = {
 "undo" : [
  {
   "operation": [ {"x":"2","y":"21"}, {"x":"x2","y":"y21"} ]
  },
  {
   "operation": [ {"x":"99","y":"88"} ]
  },
  {
   "operation": [ {"x":"32","y":"12"} ]
  }
 ]
 };
alert(hist.undo[0].operation[0].x);
alert(hist.undo[0].operation[0].y);
alert(hist.undo[2].operation[0].x);
alert(hist.undo[2].operation[0].y);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wont this only work if there is 1 undo? I need multiple undo objects that contain multiple operations. So basically, each hist object contains multiple undo objects. Each undo object contains multiple operation objects which themselves contain multiple operations. Thanks

Comment: You may be confused. From the index undo[2], it should be clear that there are 3 undo objects in there. Please have a look again. The notation ' "undo" : [ ' means that "undo" is an array, and in that array, you see 3 unnamed objects.

Answer (score 1):

([working jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/XWRyD/2))

```
var sample_operation_member = {"x": 100, "y": 250};
var sample_undo_member = { "operation" : [sample_operation_member, sample_operation_member,sample_operation_member] };

var hist = {
   "undo": [
      sample_undo_member,
      sample_undo_member,
      sample_undo_member,
      sample_undo_member
   ]
}

alert(hist.undo[0].operation[0].x);
```

Or, more verbosely:

```
var hist = {
    undo: [
        {"operation": [{"x": 100, "y":100},{"x": 100, "y":100},{"x": 100, "y":100}]},
        {"operation": [{"x": 100, "y":100},{"x": 100, "y":100},{"x": 100, "y":100}]},
        {"operation": [{"x": 100, "y":100},{"x": 100, "y":100},{"x": 100, "y":100}]},
        {"operation": [{"x": 100, "y":100},{"x": 100, "y":100},{"x": 100, "y":100}]}
    ]
}

alert(hist.undo[0].operation[0].x);
```

Comment: you might want to consider following the spec. http://www.json.org/ "A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes" While most parsers work without the quotes, it is a good idea to include them

Comment: just remembering `ObjectLiteral != SJON` should be the same, but not act always the same

Comment: Thanks again.  I've updated my answer and the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XWRyD/2/) to incorporate @Richardakacyberkiwi 's advice

Answer (score 0):

```
hist = { "undo" : [
      {"operation":[
        {"x":2,"y":21},
        {"x":3,"y":31}
      ]},
      {"operation":[
        {"x":4,"y":41},
        {"x":5,"y":51}
      ]},
      {"operation":[
        {"x":6,"y":61},
        {"x":7,"y":71}
      ]}
     ]
    }
```