# Good Javascript code

Tags: javascript, object, coding-style

I've been broadening my horizons learning javascript and I have a quick question about style. I used to use a literal notation when making my code like this.

```
var foo = {
  bar:function(){/*something*/}

};
```

but I would have problems accessing certain variables within the object, it would claim a few didn't exist nomatter what. So I started using this, cause it worked.

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = function(){/*something*/};
```

But after reading around a bit I get the impression that this style isn't preferred. Not that I liked the style, it just got things to work. Is there any best practices when using the literal notation so all my variables and such will work?

Wish I had the old code that didn't work still, but I think it was a variable pointing to another variable withing the same object literal or something like that.

Comment: So if you don't have the code that didn't work, how would you check whether what we suggest here works and solves this problem that you forgot? :)

Comment: I would also check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704618/what-is-the-difference-between-var-thing-and-function-thing-in-javascript  For yet another style. (`function foo{...}; new foo();` Which happens to be my prefered style atm)

Comment: @PetarIvanov because it's a common problem ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object literals should be a **static definition**, the moment you do calculations or logic in the literal declaration it will break. If you need logic/calculations use an **object constructor** instead.

For example

```
var o = {
  b: 4,
  c: 8, 
  d: o.b + o.c
}
```

Will cause a `TypeError` because `o` is undefined. The reason for this is that the object literal is created first *and then* assigned to the variable `o`.

So whilst your creating the object literal, the object `o` doesn't exist.

The following :

```
var o = {
  b: 4,
  c: 8, 
  d: this.b + this.c
}
```

Will work, but not like you expect it to. You cannot reference the object literal directly in the declaration. Because `this` is bound to `window` in this example and not to `o`.

**If you want to do logic use a constructor**

```
var o = new function() {
  this.b = 4;
  this.c = 8;
  this.d = this.b + this.c;
}
```

or

```
var O = function() {
  this.b = 4;
  this.c = 8;
  this.d = this.b + this.c;
}
var o = new O();
```

**Conclusion:**

As long as the object literal declaration contains no logic it is safe. (Just declare functions and properties with static values).

If the declaration contains logic it should be in a function body (like a constructor)

Comment: Related: [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202).

Comment: This helped more than you can imagine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access members of the current object via **this**

```
var foo = {
    bar: 10,
    baz: function() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: `window.bar='fail';var o = foo.baz;o();`

Comment: yep, if you copy the method to global scope, it will access variables from global scope ;-)